# How to use GLUT not in main thread on OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, glut

I once tried to open a GLUT window from a sub-thread and got lots of nasty problems. I remember this post on lists.apple.com:

```
GLUT functions may only be called from the application's main thread
```

Has anything changed in this regard with GLUT on Mac OS X ? Is there a thread-safe GLUT that let's you open windows from any thread ?

If GLUT is not an option, is there a tiny library that replaces GLUT and would work from any thread ?

**[edit]**

Here is the result of my tests triggered by the various solutions proposed as answers:

- GLFW looked nice but did not compile (current branch is 3 years old)
- Agar was another pretender but it's too big for the tiny need I had
- SDL is not BSD-license compatible and it's a huge library for code that should fit on a single file
- GLUT cannot run in any thread.

I decided to reinvent the wheel (yes, that's good sometimes) and the final class is just 200 lines of code. It let's me open and close a window from any thread (openGL draw in new thread) and I have full control on vertical sync and such (SDL uses double buffering = slow for openGL). I had to trick around the `NSApp` to properly start and stop the application (which does not use an event loop otherwise).

To those telling me that OpenGL is not thread-safe, that's not exactly true: you can run multiple OpenGL threads and the draw commands will be executed in the OpenGL state assigned to that thread. OpenGL is **thread-specific**.

If anyone needs some bare-bones code to create OpenGL windows using Cocoa: [gl_window.mm](http://github.com/rubyk/rubyk/blob/master/src/lib_objects/gl_window/macosx/gl_window.mm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLUT is not thread safe. You'll need locking primitives with whatever solution you choose to implement. I'd recommend setting up your own GL view in Cocoa and rewriting the plumbing that GLUT provides.

Take a look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/index.php) as a modern GLUT replacement. It should give you all the cross-platform you want. As far a cross-platform threading, Boost provides a portable [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Comment: All the code has to run on Mac, Windows and Linux. If there is a plumber out there that avoids me the pain to rewrite a glut equivalent, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

As a replacement for GLUT, have a look at [GLFW](http://glfw.sourceforge.net/). It's similar in purpose and workings, but better. And it does not have a `glfwMainLoop` that your program is stuck with; it allows you full control. Never since I discovered GLFW have I had a need to switch back to GLUT.

Note that GLFW is *not* thread-safe, in the sense that it is unsafe to call GLFW functions from different threads ([FAQ entry](http://glfw.sourceforge.net/faq.html#2_9)). However, as long as you call all GLFW functions from the same thread, it's your choice which thread that will be.

Comment: GLFW looked nice but the stable branch is 3 years old and it does not compile (lots of deprecation warnings and errors).

Comment: Nowadays (if not back in '10) some important GLFW functions such as glfwCreateWindow only work properly when called from the main thread on OSX due to a limitation in OSX.  The GLFW manual documents which functions are restricted to the main thread.  You can still call them from other threads, and it will work on some OSes (e.g. Windows, Linux) but not on OSX unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is GLUT is not thread safe, but OpenGL is a state machine, and therefore isn't thread safe.  Having said that, you can have multithreaded applications that use OpenGL.  Just make sure all your OpenGL calls are made from the same thread.

The next step up from GLUT on Mac OS X is the [Cocoa OpenGL Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/CocoaGL/index.html).  This is a true Cocoa application that demonstrates the Cocoa way of setting up an OpenGL window, with interactivity using the Cocoa event model.  From this starting point, it's fairly easy to add code to handle your program logic in a separate thread (or threads) from your OpenGL drawing code.